# biblatex - postcite as subscript

Tags: biblatex, natbib, subscripts

I've defined the command `\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\autocite{#2} #1}` which allows me to combine a superscripted citation with a parenthetical page reference:

> Cf. Sloterdijk<sup>1</sup> (pp. 84–85). ✓

This recovers the behavior of `natbib` within `biblatex`.  Now I'm wondering if I can do something clever: is there a way to get the page numbers stacked right below the superscript?

This doesn't give the right visual effect (with `fixltx2e`):

`Sloterdijk\supercite{sloterdijk2013change}\textsubscript{(pp. 84--85)}`

The following achieves what I was thinking of visually, but it's not using the bibliography system at all:

`Sloterdijk$^1_{\mathrm{(pp.\ 84-85)}}$.`

Maybe if I used the actual postcite argument instead of my own hack, I could do this, but I haven't figured out how to get a "real" postcite working together with superscripted numeric citations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            articletitle=true,
            url=true,
            style=nature,
            sorting=nyt,
            autocite=superscript,
            backref=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\autocite{#2} #1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{sloterdijk2013change,
  title={You Must Change Your Life},
  author={Sloterdijk, P.},
  publisher={Polity Press},
  year={2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
Cf. Sloterdijk\mycite[(pp. 84--85)]{sloterdijk2013change}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an ugly suggestion you can redefine `\supercite` which normally doesn't use `postnote` fields:

```
\newbibmacro*{postnotesub}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}
    {\printfield{postnote}}%
}

\newrobustcmd{\mkbibsubscript}[1]{%
  \unspace\allowhyphens\textsubscript{%
    \begingroup
    \protected\long\def\mkbibsuperscript##1{%
      \blx@warning{Nested subscript}%
      \mkbibbrackets{##1}}%
    \mkbibparens{#1}\endgroup}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}
   }
  {%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}%
      {\mkbibsuperscript{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}}%
      {%
       \mkbibsuperscript{\rlap{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}}%
      }%
  }%
  {}
  {%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}%
      {}%
      {%
       \mkbibsubscript{\usebibmacro{postnotesub}}%
      }%
   \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
  }
```

Related to your example `\autocite[84--85]{sloterdijk2013change}` will produce:

[image]

Here the complete MWE whereby I loaded `fixltx2e` and changed `\bibliography` to `\addbibresource` (see documentation for further information)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            articletitle=true,
            url=true,
            style=nature,
            sorting=nyt,
            autocite=superscript,
            backref=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\mycite}[2][]{\rlap{\autocite{#2}}\textsubscript{#1}}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{sloterdijk2013change,
  title={You Must Change Your Life},
  author={Sloterdijk, P.},
  publisher={Polity Press},
  year={2013}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newbibmacro*{postnotesub}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}
    {\printfield{postnote}}%
}

\newrobustcmd{\mkbibsubscript}[1]{%
  \unspace\allowhyphens\textsubscript{%
    \begingroup
    \protected\long\def\mkbibsuperscript##1{%
      \blx@warning{Nested subscript}%
      \mkbibbrackets{##1}}%
    \mkbibparens{#1}\endgroup}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}
   }
  {%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}%
      {\mkbibsuperscript{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}}%
      {%
       \mkbibsuperscript{\rlap{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}}%
      }%
  }%
  {}
  {%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}%
      {}%
      {%
       \mkbibsubscript{\usebibmacro{postnotesub}}%
      }%
   \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
  }



\begin{document}

Cf. Sloterdijk\autocite[84--85]{sloterdijk2013change}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document} 
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hss\llap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt}
\section{Student 93b427156c}
\begin{description}
    \item[number] 93b4s27156c              
    \item[name] Note that this analysis of a formative as a pair of sets of features is necessary
to impose an interpretation on an important distinction in language use.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the cool suggestion!  I tried it with: `Cf. Sloterdijk\autocite[84--85]{sloterdijk2013change} Or just Cf. Sloterdijk\supercite{sloterdijk2013change}.` -- there's a space after the second citation.  Any guess about how to remove that?

Comment: @JoeCorneli: Fixed. I forgot some `%`